# Discrete plots instead of parametric plots

Tags: plotting, drawing

I have a big iteration process and I want to look at the trajectories. Although if I consider ParametricPlot for this process, Mathematica connects points with lines. And for

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> Thin]
```

instead of a circle I am getting this:
[image]

Is there any way to just draw points? there is a version DiscretePlot but this is 3Dimensional feature.

Thank you!

Comment: `Graphics@Point@Table[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000}]`

Comment: or `ParametricPlot[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Small], Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None]`

Comment: To get a more reliable plot you can also try increasing the `PlotPoints` option. In your example you need it quite high but it works. Try for example `ParametricPlot[
 {Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]},
 {t, 0, 1000},
 PlotStyle -> Thin,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotPoints -> 3000
 ]`. Higher values of PlotPoints decrease the thickness of the resulting circle.

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000, .01}], AspectRatio -> 1]` or `ListPlot[{Re[Exp[100*I*#]], Im[Exp[100*I*#]]} & /@ 
  Range[0, 1000, .01], AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: Note that the reason that you're not getting a circle in this case is that Mathematica isn't using enough plot points;  "adjacent" points appear to be halfway around the circle from each other, and so the connecting lines are much more visible.  Increasing `PlotPoints` gives the expected results. (To get a good result it needs to be around 10000, which does take noticeably longer to plot.)

Comment: Also note that the range of `t` is much larger than it needs to be here, which is the source of all of the problems. You can get a circle by just reducing it: `ParametricPlot[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi/100}]`

Answer (score 3):

I'll **summarize the answers presented in the comments**, so the question appears answered to interested future users, in the spirit of this laudable [Meta post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1567/27951) from [Ian](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/712/ian).

The most direct answer to your question, i.e. preventing ParametricPlot from drawing connecting lines, was provided by [Simon Rochester](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8253/simon-rochester):

```
parplot = ParametricPlot[
 {Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000},
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[Small], Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> None
]
```

[image: Simon's ParametricPlot]

Adaptive sampling leads to the use of more than 3k points for the plot above, as [glance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27539/glance) noted as well:

```
Length@First@Cases[parplot, Point[a_List] -> a, Infinity]
(* Out: 3108 *)
```

---

Simon also suggested to construct the plot directly from `Graphics` primitives. Below is that suggestion, adjusted to have roughly the same number of plot points as the `ParametricPlot` above, as well as to show the axes:

```
Graphics[
 Point@Table[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000, 0.322}],
 Axes -> True
]
```

The result is visually indistinguishable from that of the `ParametricPlot` above.

---

[Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon)'s suggested approaches using `ListPlot`, applied to a table generated by `Map`ping a pure function on a `Range`, or using `Table`. The two approaches are perfectly equivalent, and I personally find the `Table` a bit more readable. Again, I adjusted the $t$ step to fall in line with the examples above.

```
ListPlot[
 Table[{Re[Exp[100*I*t]], Im[Exp[100*I*t]]}, {t, 0, 1000, .322}],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

---

It is interesting to compare timings for these approaches (these were obtained using [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html)):

```
ParametricPlot :  0.025   s
Graphics       :  0.00047 s
ListPlot/Table :  0.030   s
ListPlot/Range :  0.031   s
```

In short, constructing the plot directly from `Graphics` primitives seems to be TWO orders of magnitude faster (!!) than the `*Plot` approaches. I may have expected that the magic going on under the hood in `ParametricPlot` would slow that one down, but such a marked difference between `Graphics@Point` and the comparatively "dumber" `ListPlot` was quite unexpected to me.